# "Compiler crashed with code: 1." Trouble compiling MonoDevelop 4

Tags: compiling, monodevelop

I'm trying to compile the latest version of MonoDevelop (4.0.9) on my Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm facing errors I can not overcome. Here are my machine's configurations:

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
Mono: version 3.0.12
```

And here are the commands that I ran to download MonoDevelop:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/mono/monodevelop.git
$ cd monodevelop
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

And afterwards to compile:

```
./configure --prefix=`pkg-config --variable=prefix mono` --profile=stable
make
```

Then I faced the following errors (sorry if it's long):

```
...
Building ./Main.sln
xbuild /verbosity:quiet /nologo /property:CodePage=65001 ./Main.sln /property:Configuration=Debug
/home/mehran/git/monodevelop/main/Main.sln:  warning : Don't know how to handle GlobalSection MonoDevelopProperties.Debug, Ignoring.
:  warning CS1685: The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' is defined in multiple assemblies. Using definition from `mscorlib'
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Compiler crashed with code: 1.
:  warning CS1685: The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' is defined in multiple assemblies. Using definition from `mscorlib'
Editor/IDocument.cs(98,30): warning CS0419: Ambiguous reference in cref attribute `GetOffset'. Assuming `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Editor.IDocument.GetOffset(int, int)' but other overloads including `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Editor.IDocument.GetOffset(ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TextLocation)' have also matched
PatternMatching/INode.cs(51,37): warning CS1574: XML comment on `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.PatternMatching.PatternExtensions.Match(this ICSharpCode.NRefactory.PatternMatching.INode, ICSharpCode.NRefactory.PatternMatching.INode)' has cref attribute `PatternMatching.Match.Success' that could not be resolved
TextLocation.cs(35,23): warning CS0419: Ambiguous reference in cref attribute `Editor.IDocument.GetOffset'. Assuming `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Editor.IDocument.GetOffset(int, int)' but other overloads including `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Editor.IDocument.GetOffset(ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TextLocation)' have also matched
TypeSystem/FullTypeName.cs(87,24): warning CS0419: Ambiguous reference in cref attribute `ReflectionHelper.ParseReflectionName'. Assuming `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.ReflectionHelper.ParseReflectionName(string)' but other overloads including `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.ReflectionHelper.ParseReflectionName(string, ref int)' have also matched
TypeSystem/INamedElement.cs(59,24): warning CS0419: Ambiguous reference in cref attribute `ReflectionHelper.ParseReflectionName'. Assuming `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.ReflectionHelper.ParseReflectionName(string)' but other overloads including `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.ReflectionHelper.ParseReflectionName(string, ref int)' have also matched
TypeSystem/IType.cs(50,26): warning CS1584: XML comment on `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.IType' has syntactically incorrect cref attribute `IEquatable{IType}.Equals(IType)'
TypeSystem/IType.cs(319,38): warning CS1580: Invalid type for parameter `1' in XML comment cref attribute `GetMethods(Predicate{IUnresolvedMethod}, GetMemberOptions)'
TypeSystem/TypeKind.cs(61,17): warning CS1580: Invalid type for parameter `1' in XML comment cref attribute `IType.GetNestedTypes(Predicate{ITypeDefinition}, GetMemberOptions)'
TypeSystem/SpecialType.cs(50,52): warning CS1580: Invalid type for parameter `1' in XML comment cref attribute `IType.GetNestedTypes(Predicate{ITypeDefinition}, GetMemberOptions)'
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Compiler crashed with code: 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem on my own. I uninstalled mono through `Software Center` and compiled/installed the latest version (3.0.12) manually. But then I had to compile gtk-sharp and gnome-sharp (using their sources) and then MonoDevelop. I also need to warn you that during this process I lost my sound!